# HTML play audio using keyboard shortcut with onkeydown

Tags: javascript, html, r, shiny

I can't figure out why my function isn't working to trigger the audio. Any suggestions would be very much appreciated.

```
tags$div(
      tags$audio(id = 'targetAudio',src = sprintf("audioResources/%s.wav", trialName), type = 'audio/wav'),
      tags$button(onclick="document.getElementById('targetAudio').play()", 
                  type = 'button', '',
                  img(src = paste0(image, 'targetIcon.png'), width = 80, height = 80)),
      tags$script("
                  var target = document.getElementById('targetAudio');
                  target.onkeydown = function(e) {
                    if (e.KeyCode === 49) {
                    target.play();
                    }
                  }
                  ")
      )
```

The button correctly works to trigger the audio, but I would also want to trigger the audio by using the number '1' **(keycode = 49)** on the keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

From docs:

> You must wrap the actual script in HTML to prevent it from being passed as text.
> `tags$script(HTML("if (window.innerHeight < 400) alert('Screen too small');"))`

In your case;

```
tags$script(HTML("
  var target = document.getElementById('targetAudio');
  target.onkeydown = function(e) {
    if (e.KeyCode === 49) {
      target.play();
    }
  }
")
```

Also keep in mind, by using `target.onkeydown` you are listening keydown events on target element only. If you want to play audio with global shortcuts, you can do it like this (inside tag$script of course);

```js
var target = document.getElementById('targetAudio');
document.addEventListener('keydown', listenKey);

function listenKey(e) {
  if(e.code === 49){
    target.play();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and I tried the methods you suggest but it still doesn't work... Do you think it could be due to this being inside the shinyapp?

Comment: try `console.log(e)` after onkeydown and lets make sure the event is being trigerred by checking the console.

Comment: Still doesn't work and I really can't figure out what's causing the problem :'(

Comment: Is `keydown` event being triggered? Did you check with `console.log(e)`?